# AMD modules + QUnit

Tags: javascript, module, amd, qunit

I am using RequireJs, BackboneJs and few other libraries in my project. And I am using `QUnit` to test my modules. I am having problem mentioned here (https://github.com/jquery/qunit/issues/190).

`QUnit` attaches "module" to window and the open source libraries are being loaded as `commonjs` modules because they do something like this:

```
if(typeof module != "undefined" && module.exports) {
    module.exports = LIB_ENTITY;
} else if(typeof define != "undefined") {
   //define module
}
```

Does anyone have any fix or suggestions?

I appreciate your help!